# how to not stop excel download after closing browser in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using apache poi framework for excel functionality. Working on spring boot app.

I am getting the below exceptions when I start download, and closing browser.

**org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**

**java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

How can I continue download even though browser closed? is it possible?

Comment: "Can I continue download even though browser closed?" No, not if the browser had opened the connection for the download. Then this connection is closed when browser is closed. This implies that there can be possibilities where browser delegates downloads to other applications or services which keeps running after browser is closed. But this is not default behavior of web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Such behavior could be explained if the HTTP Client you use opens [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) to the server, and the server occasionally terminates them.

Normally, the connection to an HTTP server is closed after each response. With HTTP "keep-alive" you keep the underlying TCP connection open until certain criteria are met. What those conditions are depends on the server, which is free to close the connection after an arbitrary timeout or number of requests (just as long as it returns the response to the current request).

When the server closes such a connection the client usually reopens it again, and depending on implementation, may throw an exception or print a warning.